# How to get validate a @PathVariable before authorization in Spring MVC

Tags: spring, spring-mvc, spring-boot, spring-security, spring-validator

I have a REST handler with an endpoint for the GET verb. Where from an identifier (ObjectID of MongoDB) I get the information of that entity.

To validate that the ObjectID is valid and avoid errors when using Spring Data Mongo. I have developed a simple validator following the guidelines of the JPA bean validation standard.

```
@Target({METHOD, FIELD, ANNOTATION_TYPE, CONSTRUCTOR, PARAMETER, TYPE_USE})
@Retention(RUNTIME)
@Constraint(validatedBy = ValidObjectIdValidator.class)
@NotNull
@Documented
public @interface ValidObjectId {
    String message() default "{constraints.valid.objectid}";
    Class<?>[] groups() default {};
    Class<? extends Payload>[] payload() default {};
}


public class ValidObjectIdValidator implements ConstraintValidator<ValidObjectId, String> {

    @Override
    public void initialize(ValidObjectId constraintAnnotation) {}

    @Override
    public boolean isValid(String id, ConstraintValidatorContext context) {
        return ObjectId.isValid(id);
    }
}
```

Then I apply the variable-level validation of the controller using the following configuration:

```
@Api
@RestController("RestUserController")
@Validated
@RequestMapping("/api/v1/children/")
public class ChildrenController implements ISonHAL, ICommentHAL, ISocialMediaHAL
```

Using **@Validated** annotation at controller level.

```
@GetMapping(path = "/{id}")
    @ApiOperation(value = "GET_SON_BY_ID", nickname = "GET_SON_BY_ID", notes = "Get Son By Id",
            response = SonDTO.class)
    @PreAuthorize("@authorizationService.hasParentRole() && @authorizationService.isYourSon(#id)")
    public ResponseEntity<APIResponse<SonDTO>> getSonById(
            @Valid @ValidObjectId(message = "{son.id.notvalid}")
            @ApiParam(value = "id", required = true) @PathVariable String id) throws Throwable {
        logger.debug("Get User with id: " + id);
        return Optional.ofNullable(sonService.getSonById(id))
                .map(sonResource -> addLinksToSon(sonResource))
                .map(sonResource -> ApiHelper.<SonDTO>createAndSendResponse(ChildrenResponseCode.SINGLE_USER, HttpStatus.OK, sonResource))
                .orElseThrow(() -> { throw new SonNotFoundException(); });
    }
```

Using the **@Valid annotation on the @PathVariable.**

The problem is that I must verify that the user is currently authenticated is the parent of the child for whom he wants to see his information. This is verified by the execution of:

```
@PreAuthorize("@authorizationService.hasParentRole() && @authorizationService.isYourSon(#id)")
```

And here the error occurs. Because I must convert the received id to an ObjectID mediate `new ObjectId (id)`. And this may not be valid.

Is there any way to configure validation to occur before authorization?.

This is my configuration to enable security at the method level:

```
@EnableGlobalMethodSecurity(prePostEnabled = true, proxyTargetClass = true)
```

Thanks in advance.

Comment: It is a rather de facto pattern that authorization service should accept invalid id and return `false` (deny access) for it.

Comment: Thanks for answering. So should you check the validity of the id in the authorization service?.